# border-radius for background created with linear-gradient

Tags: css, reactjs

in my react project I created a background for the whole application. Unfortunately, I can't add round corners with border-radius. Can someone please help me with this?

App.scss

```
html {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #c9d2f0 10%, #ffe7bf 80%) no-repeat 95% 50%;
  border-radius: 0.8125rem;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: forget the idea of messing with the html element, add your own container and apply the style to it

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you're trying to make every element in your html doc to have a border radius through inheritance. Well, that is not possible, because border-radius property is [not inherited](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp)

It is always better to apply such properties on elements directly (via classes or any selector you see fit)

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Hi, thx for response. My problem was in the App.tsx. I did something wrong with the HTML skeleton, now it works and the styling is removed from the html.

Comment: If possible, Share the code in App.tsx, and describe what you changed to make the HTML skeleton wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a container/wrapper and style on it.

Like this you have way more control over the style instead of styling the  tag.